# Dash to dock in ubuntu 20.04 appears twice

Tags: 20.04, dash-to-dock

In ubuntu 20.04 dash to dock extension the dock appears twice after lock or suspend.
[image]

Comment: i installed the extension with firefox

Comment: sudo apt remove gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock resolve the problem